# Raspberry dpkg "files list file for package '<pck_name>' missing AND cannot allocate memory

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt-get, dpkg

I have the following issue:
when I try to

```
 apt-get upgrade
```

I receive some dpkg warning, (picture attached).

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php5-json' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php5' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php5-readline' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php5-cli' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'php5-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: 
    failed to allocate memory: cannot allocate memory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This happens also when I try to install these singles packages, and when I try to remove them. I also tried without success to remove the whole apache2 and php5 packages. Either apt-get autoremove and autoclean followed by update and upgrade does not change the outcome.

I have some free space on SD card, and I tried some proposed solutions to similar issues:

Tried to manually delete .deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives/ as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing)

Tried to force reinstallation as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715558/files-list-file-for-package-missing-dpkg-warning)

Also tried a bunch of similar solutions, without success...

Please, can someone point me in the right direction? This problem leads to an error launching apache2, and I can't use my websites.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: From what I can see I thinks It is you repo that cause the issue. Have you modified your repo file?  `/etc/apt/sources.list` . If no can you give me it's content. And the same for `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`

Comment: @m.nachury the content of sources.list is the default:
`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi`

the content of raspi.list is also default:
`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui`

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix your dependencies

Also `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fix your installations

Comment: the first one leave me with this error:
`Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.`

the second one also gives is an error:
`dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have the folder `/var/lib/dpkg`? if yes, what is his content `ls -a /var/lib/dpkg`

Comment: the folder is empty. tried to create manually all files(empty) and folders required, but it has not helped.

Comment: That's bad, did you by accident deleted non-necessary file in dpkg while trying to clear cache?

Comment: Try checking this [dpkg fix after accidental removal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383339/how-to-recover-deleted-dpkg-directory). Even if you haven't deleted anything. At least delete the empty files and copy they're back up from `/var/backups/` like in the link I gave you.

Comment: I saw that post. Sadly I don't have any /var/backups/ folder.